# Problem when trying to implement a Pascal's Triangles using python

Tags: python, generator

I was trying to practice generator in python to implement Pascal's Triangles. Here are my codes.

```
def triangles():
    k = 1
    l = [1,]
    while True:
        if(k == 1):
            k += 1
            yield(l)
        elif(k == 2):
            k += 1 
            l.append(1)
            yield(l)
        else:
            mid = l.copy()
            for i in range(1,k-1):
                
                a = l[i-1] + l[i]
                mid[i] = a   
            mid.append(1)
            l = mid
            k += 1
            yield(mid)
```

And when I do things like this, everything looks just fine at the beginning. This is the test code.

```
n = 0
results = []
for t in triangles():
    results.append(t)
    n = n + 1
    print(t)
    if n == 10:
        break
print(results)
```

and  here are the outputs.

```
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 3, 3, 1]
[1, 4, 6, 4, 1]
[1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1]
[1, 6, 15, 20, 15, 6, 1]
[1, 7, 21, 35, 35, 21, 7, 1]
[1, 8, 28, 56, 70, 56, 28, 8, 1]
[1, 9, 36, 84, 126, 126, 84, 36, 9, 1]
[[1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 2, 1], [1, 3, 3, 1], [1, 4, 6, 4, 1], [1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1], [1, 6, 15, 20, 15, 6, 1], [1, 7, 21, 35, 35, 21, 7, 1], [1, 8, 28, 56, 70, 56, 28, 8, 1], [1, 9, 36, 84, 126, 126, 84, 36, 9, 1]]
```

The `results` are supposed to be the first 10 lines in the output, which is also the output of every run of the generator `triangles`. However, the first element of `results`  is not [1], but [1,1].
I am really confused. When I create a list [[1]], and append it with [1,1], I got [[1], [1,1]]. Everything looks just fine. I don't know where is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need the `elif` part in the `triangle` function:

```
def triangles():
    k = 1
    l = [1]
    while True:
        if(k == 1):
            k += 1
            yield(l)
        else:
            mid = l.copy()
            for i in range(1,k-1):
                
                a = l[i-1] + l[i]
                mid[i] = a   
            mid.append(1)
            l = mid
            k += 1
            yield(mid)
n = 0
results = []
for t in triangles():
    results.append(t)
    n = n + 1
    if n == 10:
        break
print(results)
```

Comment: You are right. Thank you. But I still don't get what's wrong with my code. Because the outputs of these two functions are the same if you print it in every iteration. But when you append it into list "results", it gets different. And if you set n=9, results will be [[1]]. When you set n=8, results will be [[1,1],[1,1]]. How could [[1]] append [1,1] be [[1,1],[1,1]]?